# How to implement the API/SPI Pattern in Java?

Tags: java, api, design-patterns, slf4j

I am creating a framework that exposes an API for developers to use:

```
public interface MyAPI {
    public void doSomeStuff();

    public int getWidgets(boolean hasRun);
}
```

All the developers should have to do is code their projects against these API methods. I also want them to be able to place different "drivers"/"API bindings" on the runtime classpath (the same way JDBC or SLF4J work) and have the API method calls (`doSomeStuff()`, etc.) operate on different 3rd party resources (files, servers, whatever). Thus the same code and API calls will map to operations on different resources depending on what driver/binding the runtime classpath sees (i.e. `myapi-ftp`, `myapi-ssh`, `myapi-teleportation`).

How do I write (and package) an SPI that allows for such runtime binding, **and** then maps `MyAPI` calls to the correct (concrete) implementation? In other words, if `myapi-ftp` allows you to `getWidgets(boolean)` from an FTP server, how would I could this up (to make use of both the API and SPI)?

Bonus points for concrete, working Java code example! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Take a look at the java.util.ServiceLoader class.

In general, the idea is this:

API Jar

Supply the interface

Use the ServiceLoader class to lookup the implementation

Binding/Driver Jar

Implement the interface

Create the file META-INF/ and specify the classname that implements it

There's a good example right in the javadocs:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html

### API Jar

```
package com.foo;

public interface FooInterface { ... }

public class FooInterfaceFactory {
  public static FooInterface newFooInstance() {
    ServiceLoader<FooInterface> loader = ServiceLoader.load(FooInterface.class);
    Iterator<FooInterface> it = loader.iterator();
    // pick one of the provided implementations and return it.
  }
```

### Binding Jar

```
package com.myfoo;
public class MyFooImpl implements FooInterface { ... }

META-INF/com.foo.FooInterface
    com.myfoo.MyFooImpl
```

### **EDIT**
SPI Example

```
public interface FooSpi { 
   void accepts(String url);
   FooInterface getFooInstance();
}


public class FooInterfaceFactory {
  public static FooInterface getFooInterfaceInstance(String url) {
    ServiceLoader<FooSpi> loader = ServiceLoader.load(FooSpi.class);
    Iterator<FooSpi> it = loader.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
       FooSpi fooSpi = it.next();
       if (fooSpi .accepts(url)) {
         return fooSpi.getFooInstance();
       }
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

And of course, change the filename to com.foo.FooSpi and provide an implementation of FooSpi.  That will allow you to segregate the public API from the Spi interface.

If you want to hide the accepts method, you could always have a second interface which is your public API.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer @Matt (+1) - quick question though: where would the SPI come into place? I guess now I'm confused as to which classes/methods represent the **API** vs. which classes/methods represent the **SPI**. Thanks again!

Comment: You can do whatever you want with the "FooInterface" methods you look up.  JDBC is not done this way, it's done in via calls to DriverManager.registerDrive in static init blocks in each Driver class (hence the need for Class.forName so you load the driver, and it's static block registers it with DriverManager).  There's nothing to say the factory method couldn't take some other type of parameter which helps you decide which implementation to choose.  see the edit.

Answer (score 3):

Well you know that API are what clients use, and SPI is what your library use internally.

You shall have classes which implement your API classes, which depend on SPI interfaces, and have some implementations for your SPI.

Most of the time SPI interfaces contain low level methods (abstraction for direct working with FTP, SSH and... in your example), and your library provides higher level operations for your clients.

Maybe your SPI interfaces would be such as:

```
public interface ProtocolSPI {
    boolean isCompatibleWithUrl(String url);
    Handle connect(String url, Map<String, Object> parameters);
    int readData(Handle handle, byte[] bytes);
    void writeData(Handle handle, byte[] bytes, int startIndex, int length);
    void closeHandle(Handle handle);
}
```

and you have code which depends on this interface for working with replaceable part.

You may have a ProtocolSPIFactory which uses `java.util.ServiceLoader` to find available implementations of your ProtocolSPI (in the class-path), then instantiates them and by calling `isCompatibleWithUrl` finds out which implementation to use for a specific `url`.