# Java classes with 'dynamic' number of methods?

Tags: java, design-patterns

let’s say that we have a class to which occasionally are added new checks and you end with something like describe below:

```
class CheckList{
  check1(){
   //do something
  }
  check1(){
   //do something
  }
  //...
  checkN(){
   //do something
  }
}
```

and you want to call all the checks in a straightforward way

I have considered the following options:

1. use reflexion to get the methods, iterate and executing them
2. use a list containing the check names, iterate and execute them
3. use annotations to load, populate a map and go to 2
4. use an interface, create classes implementing it and instantiate the checks through a loop and execute them

what I want to avoid is the need modify other classes each time that
a new check is added.

**is there a design pattern/recipe known to achieve such thing?**

Note:
the order doesn't matter at all

Edit: thank you for all your valuable answers, I don't have a problem creating more than one file, I know that I can create a list/method that calls the rest of the methods

```
class Caller{
 executeAll(){
  check1();
  check2();
  checkN();
 }
 //list add checkN
 //foreach check in list execute it
}
```

But the idea is to make it as much automated as possible so that when adding a new check the changes made be minimal and the people who will be adding new checks don't have to worry about adding his/her new check to a list of checks (this would make it less error prone)

if there is no way to avoid so, I think I can live with it I just was looking for some alternatives

Comment: do the checks happen in order? if so perhaps a chain of responsibility could be applied where each check chains to the next..

Comment: Why not have a class containing a list of `Check` objects each of which know how to do one `Check`?  Don't look for _names,_ just have a list of things all implementing a `Check` interface.

Comment: by having another class containing the list of checks would require editing a second file each time that a check is added and is what I would like to avoid

Comment: Why though? I don't see anything wrong with that. And if having the second file is a problem, try defining the checks in the same file.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the issue. It seems you're happy to add new check methods to this class but you don't want to change other classes that call all the checks. Is that correct? If so, just have a `checkAll` method in the `CheckList` class that calls all the other checks. That's clearly too obvious to be a real answer but perhaps you can explain why it isn't an answer so we can understand the problem better.

Comment: You don't even need this class.  All you need is the `Check` interface - or you could even use the `Runnable` interface.  Then if you have an `ArrayList<Check>` or `ArrayList<Runnable>` called `myChecks` (for example),  you can just call `myChecks.forEach(r->r.run());`

Comment: playing with Runnable without the need to start new Threads? bad idea :)

Comment: @WrRaThY Would you like to explain why you think that?

Comment: just for clarity. naming is one of the most important things in programming and using something called "Runnable" (that is widely known to be used in Threads) in a single threaded class might cause some confusion. Plus - I think that he will need to accept some arguments, so [consumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) sounds like a slightly better idea (I'd probably create an interface of my own though)

Comment: Yeah, I don't agree.  **Runnable** is something that you **run**.  It looks like that's what these checks are.  Assuming they're void and take no arguments, I can think of no better way of signalling "this is something we're going to **run**" than using `Runnable`.  Plenty of people using Java 8 do this already - I don't see it as an anti-pattern at all.

Comment: A design pattern to implement option 4 is the service provider interface (SPI) explained in detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11405686/7694476

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your exact business requirements, but it seems like you need something similar to "Intercepting Filter Pattern"
[image]

According to the picture above the class that you already have (CheckList) would be split up to FilterManager and FilterChain (just FilterChain might suffice also. In your case - CheckChain for example).

check1(), checkN), etc method would be extracted to an interface (Filter on the picture, probably Check in your case)

You can implement concrete checkN() methods as either classes implementing this interface or as lambdas. In case of the latter you might want to check ([here is a list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html)) if there are some existing functional interfaces that meet your needs (there probably are)

something like that at least. hope that helps :)

[Intercepting Filter Pattern explained and picture source at the same time](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/intercepting_filter_pattern.htm)

Comment: this pattern is similar to what I have, however, the remaining problem is the same,  each new Filter needs to be added manually 'filters.add(filter);'  right? this extra step I was I was trying to automate

Comment: then I'd say that you pretty much nailed with point 3 - use annotations to find all checks (but that needs an additional annotation to be defined and parsed). You may also just search for all classes implementing Check interface using reflection and add them to CheckChain. I'd probably go with that

Answer (score 0):

How about write it as a unit test? Each check would just be another unit test in the same test class and by running the whole test class as a unit test you wouldn't have to do anything other than add in a new check (test)

Comment: I will go with an interface due to the other requirements that I have but thank you by the suggestion

Comment: Ok, no problem. it seems like this meets all your needs though, I'd be curious why it doesn't work for you.